# Cumulative Sum in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query that gets the cumulative sum of a column in one of my tables.  It looks like this:

```
set @csum := 0;
select order_date, Amount, (@csum := @csum + Amount) as cumulative_sum
from Orders
order by order_date
```

However, when running this, I get all NULLs for the cumulative_sum.  Anything I"m doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Why not just do sum(Amount) as cumulative_sum....

Comment: It occurs to me that if you don't explicitly declare `@csum`, it's probably going to be initialised as an INT, and 'Amount' is probably - what, decimal? Try `set @csum := 0.0;`

Comment: Mike K, 100% correct.  How would I declare it as an INT (if I didn't want decimals)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just doing:

```
select order_date, Amount, sum(Amount) as cumulative_sum
from Orders
order by order_date
```

If you need to store the value in a variable then you could do:

```
SELECT @Variable = sum(Amount)
from Orders
```

And maybe add a `GroupBy` if you wanted to sum the amounts per day

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  The above query you gave will only give one row that sums all the Amounts.  What I want is a cumulative sum over time, so if the Amounts were, 1, 5, 7, 10, the cumulative column should be 1, 6, 13, 23.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `Amount` could sometimes be `NULL`.  Try this version:

```
select o.order_date, o.Amount,
       (@csum := @csum + coalesce(o.Amount, 0)) as cumulative_sum
from Orders o cross join
     (select @csum := 0) params
order by o.order_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8, a much better approach than using MySQL's vendor specific variables (and relying on the non-declarative nature of their calculation) is to use SQL standard [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/). Your query can be rewritten as such:

```
SELECT
  order_date,
  amount,
  sum(amount) OVER (ORDER BY order_date)
FROM orders
ORDER BY order_date
```